# Trouble to change user.is_staff 's value

Tags: python, django

I create a custom Staff model and ModelForm in my project. By default, A Staff is created without staff permission.In other world,User.is_staff = False. The permission can be set later in updatstaff. In my updatestaff, I try to offer a staff permission by calling user.is_staff = True. However, the user.is_staff is alway default value(False), and nothing changes at all. Can some one tell me what the problem is ?

```
In views.py

def updatestaff(request,id=None):

    instance = get_object_or_404(Staff,id=id)
    if request.POST:
        staff_form = StaffForm(request.POST or None,instance=instance)
        if staff_form.is_valid():

            old_user = User.objects.get(username= request.POST.get('name'))

            if request.POST.get('authorized'):
                old_user.is_staff = True
            else:
                old_user.is_staff = False
            old_user.save()
            staff_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/dataInfo/staff_view/')
    else:
        staff_form = StaffForm(instance=instance)
    return render_to_response('dataInfo/update_staff.html', {'form': staff_form,'id':instance.id}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


In models.py

  class Staff(models.Model):
    yes_or_no = ((True, 'Yes'),(False, 'No'))
    male_or_female = ((True,'Male'),(False,'Female'))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank = False, null = False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,blank = False, null = False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank = False, null = False)
    gender = models.BooleanField(default = True, choices = male_or_female)
    birthday = models.DateField(default =None,blank = False, null = False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    authorized = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices = yes_or_no) 
    store_id = models.ForeignKey(Store,default=1) 

In forms.py

class StaffForm(forms.ModelForm):

store_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Store.objects.all(),empty_label="--------") # select values ?
class Meta:
    model = Staff
    fields = ('name','email','password','gender','birthday','authorized','store_id')
    widgets = {'authorized':forms.RadioSelect,
               'gender':forms.RadioSelect,
                'birthday':SelectDateWidget(years=range(date.today().year-50,date.today().year))
    }
```

Comment: When you do `old_user.save()` and the `staff_form.save()`, does your `staff_form` maybe overwrite the previously saved `old_user` with the updated `is_staff` value? Because in your question, you posted a `SaleForm` that of completely unrelated to your question, but you didn't post the `StaffForm`.

Comment: sorry, post wrong code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never assume that `request.POST.get(...)` could give you right data type. What you get back is an `unicode`. So, `bool('True')` is `True` and `bool('False')` is also `True`. In your case it will always `True`. There is not clear why `old_user.is_staff` can not be updated to `True`. What you could try now ist that you call `old_user.save()` after `staff_form.save()` :

```
        if request.POST.get('authorized')=='True':
            old_user.is_staff = True
        else:
            old_user.is_staff = False

        staff_form.save()
        old_user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

@trantu's answer explains the problem with your code, but you should never check if the user is authorised by checking the POST parameters, as a user can post whatever they want with the form.

You should use something like this instead:

```
if request.user.is_staff():  # Or admin, or checking the permissions of the user.
```